# Button background not changing on hover

Tags: html, css, button, background, hover

I've created a button as a link using the usual methods, however, I am encountering a curious issue where the background colour is not changing on hover, when it should.

I've probably missed something really obvious, but I can't for the life of me find it.

The code in question is:

```
.downloadbtn {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #06bce4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #06bce4 0%, #0589d4 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#06bce4), color-stop(100%,#0589d4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #06bce4 0%,#0589d4 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #06bce4 0%,#0589d4 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #06bce4 0%,#0589d4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #06bce4 0%,#0589d4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#06bce4', endColorstr='#0589d4',GradientType=0 );
    border: 1px solid #076ca0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(64, 209, 236, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(64, 209, 236, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(64, 209, 236, 1);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
}

.downloadbtn :hover {
    background: green;
}
```

A JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Xxaf/

Comment: Remove empty space between `.downloadbtn :hover` should be `.downloadbtn:hover`.

Comment: You have no idea how stupid I feel right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated fiddle. You added a space between the selector and `:hover` http://jsfiddle.net/4Xxaf/1/

Comment: You have no idea how stupid I feel right now. Thanks.

Comment: It's just one of those days :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in your code

```
.downloadbtn:hover{
    background: green;
}
```